# ASP.NET 5 Failing to install ASP.NET 5 NuGet Package

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I have a ASP.NET 5 NuGet package called [Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6/1.0.11). I am unable to to reference the NuGet package in my ASP.NET 5 website. Here is my project.json file referencing `"Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6": "1.0.11"`.

```
{
  // Omitted

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta6",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.1",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-23109",
    "Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6": "1.0.11"
  },

  // Omitted
}
```

When I add the package above, the references in the project shows an error and I get the following printed in the output window:

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
C:\Users\Rehan Saeed\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7-12364\bin\dnx.exe "C:\Users\Rehan Saeed\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7-12364\bin\lib\Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling\Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.dll" restore "C:\Temp\WebApplication2\WebApplication2" -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU"
Microsoft .NET Development Utility CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta7-12364
Restoring packages for C:\Temp\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\project.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  CACHE http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/
  CACHE https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/boilerplate.web.mvc6/index.json
  GET http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6
  Response from http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6' is not a valid NuGet v2 service response.
  GET http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6
  Response from http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6' is not a valid NuGet v2 service response.
  GET http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6'
Error: FindPackagesById: Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6
  Response from http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6' is not a valid NuGet v2 service response.
----------
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Response from http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6' is not a valid NuGet v2 service response. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: 'doctype' is an unexpected token. The expected token is 'DOCTYPE'. Line 2, position 3.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnexpectedToken(String expectedToken1, String expectedToken2)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.NuGetv2Feed.EnsureValidFindPackagesResponse(Stream stream, String uri)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.NuGetv2Feed.EnsureValidFindPackagesResponse(Stream stream, String uri)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.NuGetv2Feed.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore>b__0(Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.HttpSource.<GetAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.NuGetv2Feed.<FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RemoteWalkProvider.<FindLibrary>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibrary>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryByVersion>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryMatch>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryEntry>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<CreateGraphNode>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<CreateGraphNode>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<CreateGraphNode>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<RestoreForProject>d__70.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass69_0.<<Execute>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<Execute>d__69.MoveNext()
----------
Restore failed
Response from http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6' is not a valid NuGet v2 service response.
NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\Rehan Saeed\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
Feeds used:
    https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/
    http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU
```

What's going wrong?

**UPDATE**

These are my NuGet package feeds:

1. nuget.org - https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
2. My Get - http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster
3. Microsoft .NET - https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/

**UPDATE 2**

I ran `dnu restore --ignore-failed-sources` and got the following output, where it still can't find my NuGet package. The strange thing is that I can reference 1.0.10 of the same package from my ASP.NET 5 project but not from an ASP.NET 5 class library.

```
Restoring packages for C:\Temp\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\project.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json 130ms
  GET http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/
  OK http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/ 142ms
  GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/boilerplate.web.mvc6/index.json
  GET http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6
  Response from http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6' is not a valid NuGet v2 service response.
  GET http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6'
  OK https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/boilerplate.web.mvc6/index.json 103ms
Warning: FindPackagesById: Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6
  Response from http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6' is not a valid NuGet v2 service response.
  GET http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6
  Response from http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6' is not a valid NuGet v2 service response.
Unable to locate Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6 >= 1.0.11
Writing lock file C:\Temp\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 1210ms elapsed

Errors in C:\Temp\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\project.json
    Unable to locate Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6 >= 1.0.11

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\Rehan Saeed\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/
    http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/
```

Comment: Can you post all the nuget feeds you are using? You can find this under Tools->Options->Package Manager

Comment: I'm on my phone so I cant check, but try deselecting all feeds except the feed with the boilerplate package and then run Update-Package -reinstall Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6 in the package console.

Comment: The feed url is wrong. It should be https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried deleting the project.lock.json file and re-opening Visual Studio which usually solves this problem for me.

I have since retried installing version 1.0.11 of the package and it magically worked. Since previous versions were working and I made no changes to the project or my installation, I suspect this to be a NuGet package on-boarding problem. It has taken three days for NuGet to register the new version of the package.

Comment: Deleting the project.lock.json solved the problem here.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a myget bug. I opened a bug on dnu anyway (see it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2496)) and also pinged the myget folks.

The issue is that `http://MyGet.org/aspnetmaster/FindPackagesById()?id='Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6'` returns 200 OK and HTML when the package is not found and we try to parse it as XML.

You can pass `--ignore-failed-sources` to dnu restore to unblock yourself.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. See my updated question. It should be going to NuGet, not MyGet for my package but it isn't able to get it from there.

Comment: It looks on all feeds and since one of them is returning something incorrect, it fails. The feed should include a /F: myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2 . Just like the feed here: https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/NuGet.Config#L6

Comment: Even with the ```--ignore-failed-sources``` option? I'll try adding v2 feed this evening. Can I add this in VS Options or do I need to have a NuGet.config file?

Comment: Works in VS. By the way, the MyGet folks fixed the issue so you might not see the crash anymore. But please do update the feed with the correct url

Comment: I updated the VS -> Options feed URL. I no longer get an exception but I still get ```Unable to locate Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6 >= 1.0.11```. Is it working for you?